# window.addEventlListener('load', function(){}) never got executed

Tags: jquery, html, dom, tizen

I am using jQuery to write a web app. Basically I have two local html files:  index.html, feed.html. The app is launched with the index.html, and inside the index.html, I have an anchor  that launches the 2nd html page.

For some reason, the window.addEventListener('load',) is never get called for the feed.html. Here is  my javascript and their order in the two html files:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>GearFeed</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="lib/tau/themes/default/tau.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Channel List -->
    <div class="ui-page" id="main">
        <header class="ui-header">
            <h2 class="ui-title">Your Lists</h2>
        </header>
        <!--Subscribed Channel List -->
        <div class="ui-content">
            <ul class="ui-listview">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>  

    <!-- Popup for notification -->
    <div id="popupToast" class="ui-popup ui-popup-toast">
        <div id="popupText" class="ui-popup-content"></div>
    </div>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/tau/js/tau.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/sap.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/lowBatteryCheck.js"></script>
</html>
```

And the feed.html file is very similar:
feed.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Section changer</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet"  href="../lib/tau/themes/default/tau.css">
<!-- <script src="../js/test.js"></script> -->
</head>
<body>
    <div id="feed-page" class="ui-page">
        <div id="feed-content" class="ui-content">
            <!-- section changer has only one child. -->
            <div id="feed-section">
                <section style="text-align:center" >
                    <h3> LEFT2 PAGE </h3>
                </section>
                <section style="text-align:center">
                    <h3> LEFT1 PAGE </h3>
                </section>
                <section class="section-active" style="text-align:center">
                    <h3> MAIN PAGE </h3>
                </section>
                <section style="text-align:center">
                    <h3> RIGHT1 PAGE </h3>
                </section>
                <section style="text-align:center">
                    <h3> RIGHT2 PAGE </h3>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="../js/feeddetail.js"></script>
    </div>

    <div id="loading" class="ui-page">
        <img src="../images/waiting.gif" style="padding: 140px 140px 140px 140px;"/>
    </div>

</body>
<script src="../lib/tau/js/tau.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="../js/app.js"></script>
<script src="../js/test.js"></script>
</html>
```

I tried to put the window.addEventListener('load') in three different javascript (**app.js, feeddetail.js, test.'s**) Here is my code for the load event:

```
( function () {
    window.addEventListener('load', function(){
        console.log("page load event called!");
        $('#loading').show()
        $('#feed-page').hide();
    });
}());
```

It's get called in app.js, but only when the index.html is loaded. It's never get call if I put this code in the feeddetail.js or test.js. I really confused why it's not get called.

the way I launch feed.html is

```
$('#main ul').append('<li><a href="html/feed.html" onclick="getFeed(\'' + url + '\');">' + name + '</a></li>');
```

used in the app.js code.

I hope someone could answer my question. Please note I have to load the feeddetail.js inside the body of feed.html, otherwise the formate of feed.html is not correct for the target devices.

Comment: Why are you using `addEventListener()` if you're using jQuery? `$(window).on('load', function() { ... });` is the idiom you would use there ... of course, assuming that you load jQuery *first* :)

Comment: hi @Jack thanks for the comments. i actually found out this is caused by the 3rd party js framework i loaded. it's a query extension/wrapper, it still all events.

Comment: @chengluo if you solved your problem on your own, please post your answer, so others may learn from it in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

The window.addEventListener('load', function(){}) is called actually. I actually found out that the 3rd party js framework I included tau.js is utilise the jQuery page, i should call the 3rd party library event for the page e.g. tau.changePage($('#main')) to trigger the page show and hide event.